# Como obtenho resposta json no javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o link:

```
https://dominio.com/apiJSON.php?data={"login":"email@email.com","senha":"Minhasenha","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":2799999999,"msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer","data":"2015-10-19 01:07:52"}}}
```

Colando esse link no navegador com os parametros corretos obtenho a seguinte resposta no navegador:

```
{"tip":1,"msg":[{"numero":2799999999,"id":"1234","status":1}]}
```

Quero pegar essa resposta e trabalhar ela em javascript ou  jquery. Preciso trabalhar essas informações. Alguem pode me ajudar? Obrigado!!!

Obs: Fiz essa pergunta e consegui em php. Porem preciso trabalhar ela em outra linguagem por que php o servidor barrou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago, me parece um pouco estranho passar um json como string para uma API, especialmente por GET.

mas você pode consumir esta URL de duas formas: AJAX ou JSONP:

**AJAX**

```
var json = {
    "login":"email@email.com",
    "senha":"Minhasenha",
    "campanha":"ID 1234",
    "mensagens":{
        "1":{
            "numero":2799999999,
            "msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer",
            "data":new Date(2015, 9, 19, 1, 7, 52)
        }
    }
};

var data = new FormData();
data.append("data", JSON.stringify(json)):

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("GET", "https://dominio.com/apiJSON.php", true);
httpRequest.responseType = "json";
httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
            console.log(httpRequest.response): //seu objeto JSON;
            /* Faça alguma coisa com o "httpRequest.response" */
        } else {
            console.log("Ocorreu um Erro");
        }       
    }
})
httpRequest.send(data);
```

**JSONP**

Note que adicionei mais um argumento na sua URL, `callback=minhaFuncao`, o parametro callback define o nome da funcão que vai receber o objeto json obtido como retorno da requisição.

```
var json = {
    "login":"email@email.com",
    "senha":"Minhasenha",
    "campanha":"ID 1234",
    "mensagens":{
        "1":{
            "numero":2799999999,
            "msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer",
            "data": new Date(2015, 9, 19, 1, 7, 52)
        }
    }
};  

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://dominio.com/apiJSON.php?data=" + JSON.stringify(json) + "&callback=minhaFuncao";
var minhaFuncao = function(data) {  
    /* data é o objeto JSON retornado pelo script acima */
}
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Vlw, vou tentar seu exemplo e lhe retorno amigo!

Comment: OI, desculpe minha ignorancia, mas como eu pego o resultado dessa funcao? Na verdade o que eu preciso é somente do parametro campanha. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Thiago, campanha está no seu json usado no `request`, então para acessa-lo você não precisa fazer uma requisição, seja por `AJAX` ou `JSONP`... basta usar `var campanha = json.campanha;`

Comment: Entendi. É que existe um parametro chamado saldo, que ficaria assim no seu codigo: ( "saldo" : "" ), sim ele é vazio. Ai quando executa o link do json ele retorna o numero saldo. Quando tento fazer do modo que falou ele retorna so o valor que ta acima. Como proceder?

Comment: @Thiago, no exemplo acima, você consegue acessar o `response` na parte comentada do codigo, por exemplo, se o retorno é `{ saldo: "" }` então use `var saldo = httpRequest.response.saldo;` (`AJAX`) ou `var saldo = data.saldo;` (`JSON`).

Comment: No json seria saldo = data.saldo ou saldo = json.saldo?

Comment: @Thiago, se usar `JSONP`, sera `data.saldo`

Answer (score 1):

Fazer uma chamada de ajax creio que é a melhor maneira, tendo em conta que a sua pergunta é de javascript vou postar de acordo, manter em mente que com jquery ou outras libs poderia reduzir bastante este código:

```
var xmlhttp;
var data;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           data = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
       else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
           alert('There was an error 400')
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
       }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", 'https://dominio.com/apiJSON.php?data={"login":"email@email.com","senha":"Minhasenha","campanha":"ID 1234","mensagens":{"1":{"numero":2799999999,"msg":"Uma mensagem qualquer","data":"2015-10-19 01:07:52"}}}', true);
xmlhttp.send();

// agora vamos tranformar a string JSON num objeto de javascript caso o pedido tenha sido bem sucedido:
if (typeof data != 'undefined') {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
}
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Vlw amigo. Vou tentar aqui e lhe retorno.